# How to multiply the contents of my LinkedList using a while loop and an Iterator

Tags: java, oop, while-loop, linked-list

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Multiply {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        LinkedList<Integer>num = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        num.add("1");
        num.add("2");
        num.add("3");
        num.add("4");
        num.add("5");

        product( num );
    }

    public static void product(LinkedList<Integer> list) {
        int index = 0;
        Iterator<Integer>productw = list.iterator();
        Integer next = productw.next()

        while (productw.hasNext()) {
            index++;
            System.out.println("The product of the numbers is = " + num);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your linked list consists of strings. What answer do you expect from multiplying strings?

Comment: I think it should be integer. I just need 120 as an answer.

Comment: My while loop is incomplete. I'm stuck and I don't know what to do next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially have a multiplication identity ( i.e., 1 ) before your while loop. And keep multiplying to it the iterator values.

Psuedo - code :

```
public static void product(LinkedList<Integer> list) 
{
    Iterator<Integer>productw = list.iterator();
    int result = 1;
    for( int i=0; i<productw.size(); ++i ) {
        result *= productw.get(i) ;
    }
    // result has the answer
}
```

**Edit 1:**

The above loop assumes that the list has at least 1 element. If list has no elements, then zero must be the answer which I assume you can easily program it.

Comment: I think thats more help than we should be giving here.

Comment: @RN: That's true. But Makurian1 has at least tried something without just blindly asking the question.

Comment: @Makurian1 - There is a modification in the loop, check out !

Answer (score 0):

You need to define an initial value for the product
And then change it in the loop

Also...Your loop will print the statement multiple times- you don't want that- right ?

HTH

Comment: Is my LinkedList<String>num = new etc. correct or should it be a LinkedList<Integer>num = new...?

Comment: Can you multiple "Makurian" * "Makurian" ? No. So you need List of numericals